# Firewall rule for local, interactive users?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I want to add a firewall rule that applies to a local interactive user. The intention is to clamp down the box, and only allow web and mail related connections, and update service connections. On occasion, I'll need to open a browser to look up a setting so I may need to allow the outbound connection when I'm sitting at the keyboard.

The [Linux iptables Pocket Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596005695) does not address the topic.

**Question**: Is it possible to add a firewall rule that filters based on "local user" and an "interactive user" objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter outgoing packets based on the uid of the originating process. For example:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner some_user -j DROP
```

iptables is not able to distinguish between interactive and non-interactive processes. But you might want to look into the [Linux CGROUP](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt) for this. Specifically, the [net_cls subsystem](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/net_cls.txt). You can tag packets with the net_cls subsystem, and then filter them with iptables. So the process would be to first put the interactive user's shell in a net_cls cgroup which tags outgoing packets, and then filter those packet's with iptables.